# HOW TO - jQuery Toggle Text View

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have been working on a jQuery HTML CSS I have got most of the part right. What I want to do is when I click on the name the hidden text should slide down -- I got this to work. But I have 4-5 such names and when I click on the 2nd name the 1st one should hide back and so on

here is my code

```
 /*JQUERY CODE */

 jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery('#toggle li').click(function () {

    var text = jQuery(this).children('div.slide');

    if (text.is(':hidden')) {
        text.slideDown('200');
        jQuery(this).children('span').html('-');
        jQuery(this).children('.selected').css('color','#a61607');
    } else {
        text.slideUp('200');
        jQuery(this).children('span').html('+');
        jQuery(this).children('.selected').css('color','#878484');      
    }

});

});
```

/* HTML CODE */

```
<ul id="toggle">
  <li>
    <h3 class="selected">TEST 1</h3>
    <span>+</span>
    <div class="slide">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam laoreet consequat sem, a venenatis purus mollis in. Mauris bibendum dui eget nunc sagittis sit amet placerat tortor euismod. Duis blandit urna in lorem venenatis condimentum.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3 class="selected">TEST 2</h3>
    <span>+</span>
    <div class="slide">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam laoreet consequat sem, a venenatis purus mollis in. Mauris bibendum dui eget nunc sagittis sit amet placerat tortor euismod. Duis blandit urna in lorem venenatis condimentum..</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3 class="selected">TEST 3</h3>
    <span>+</span>
    <div class="slide">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam laoreet consequat sem, a venenatis purus mollis in. Mauris bibendum dui eget nunc sagittis sit amet placerat tortor euismod. Duis blandit urna in lorem venenatis condimentum.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quick solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery('#toggle li').click(function () {
    $('.slide').slideUp('200');
    $('#toggle span').html('+');
    $('.selected').css('color','#878484');
    var text = jQuery(this).children('div.slide');

    if (text.is(':hidden')) {
        text.slideDown('200');
        jQuery(this).children('span').html('-');
        jQuery(this).children('.selected').css('color','#a61607');
    } 
});

});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Jznbh/

Comment: with this you are "resetting" all the "li" and then opening the one you clicked

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the easiest (but maybe not so pretty) way to do this:

```
if(text.is(':hidden'))
{
    jQuery('#toggle li > div.slide:not(:hidden)').click();
    text.slideDown('200');
    jQuery(this).children('span').html('-');
    jQuery(this).children('.selected').css('color','#a61607');
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate that worked. But I choose to use the solution below :) Thanks for ur help :)

Comment: @Zerosleep, if an answer worked for you, please accept it (green checkmark) so others can find the solution, too.

Comment: Done :) Thanks... All three of them worked for me... I chose the best 1.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the top of the `jQuery('#toggle li').click()` function:

```
jQuery(this).siblings().children('div.slide').slideUp();
```

This will slide an open `div`s up while the selected one slides down. You may also want to take a look at [jQuery UI's accordion feature](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/).